# DB2 LOOP statement with cursor terminating early

Tags: loops, db2

I have a stored procedure in DB2 (iSeries V5R3M0) which opens a cursor and enters a loop statement.  The loop fetches the next row from the input (work queue) table, processes the record, then deletes the row from the input table.  The process works fine, except that a random number of rows is processed before the loop terminates - often 1 row, sometimes 2 and occasionally 3 rows.

Does anyone have any ideas why it finishes early?  I can't see any faults in the logic, so I am assuming it maybe to do with deleting the input row, but in that case why does it sometimes process 2 or 3 rows?

Here is a stripped down version of the procedure: -

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DOTRANSFER (
 OUT PROCESSED INTEGER)
LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN
DECLARE V_PTNO INTEGER ;
*** lot more declares
--
DECLARE AT_END SMALLINT DEFAULT 0 ;
DECLARE NOT_FOUND CONDITION FOR SQLSTATE '02000' ;
DECLARE CURREQUESTS ASENSITIVE NO SCROLL CURSOR WITH HOLD WITHOUT RETURN FOR
    SELECT *
    FROM PENDTRPF
    ORDER BY PTNO ;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT_FOUND
    SET AT_END = 1 ;
--
-- Initialise
--
SET PROCESSED = 0 ;
OPEN CURREQUESTS ;
FETCH_LOOP : LOOP
    --
    -- Fetch the next transfer request
    --
    FETCH CURREQUESTS INTO
        V_PTNO , ...;
    IF AT_END <> 0 THEN
        LEAVE FETCH_LOOP ;
    END IF ;
*** Initialisation code
    --
    -- Start the update
    --
    COMMIT ;
*** Update or insert target table records
    --
    -- Done
    --
    DELETE FROM PENDTRPF WHERE PTNO = V_PTNO ;
    SET PROCESSED = PROCESSED + 1 ;
    COMMIT ;
END LOOP ;
END@
```

Comment: I don't know what's causing itv (Looks like the delete clear records from the cursor?) But, have you tried a "positioned delete": DECLARE CURSOR... FOR UPDATE..., followed by DELETE FROM ... CURRENT OF. I wonder if that would work the same. http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=%2Fsqlp%2Frbafycursorexamp.htm

Comment: Thanks, I can try that.  Yes, I am deleting records from the input cursor as they are processed - records may potentially be added at any time so I can't do a bulk delete at the end.

Comment: If you expect to loop and `FETCH` maybe two rows with the same value for `PTNO`, be aware that your `DELETE` is going to try to delete both of those rows as soon as the first one has been processed. In that sense, you're doing a kind of 'bulk DELETE' of all rows that match the `WHERE` clause. Two rows would be deleted though you've only FETCHed one. That's a big reason why only the `CURRENT OF` row should be deleted.